# Aurelia Binding Change.delegate Not Firing (JQueryUI Datepicker)

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, datepicker, aurelia

I'm trying to use a jqueryui datepicker and I've almost got it working. I have a custom component that looks something like this (got some code online)

```
@inject(Element)
export class Checkbox {
    @bindable({ defaultBindingMode: bindingMode.twoWay }) value = {};
    @bindable datepicker;
    @bindable label;
    @bindable inputLabel;
    element: Element = null;

    constructor(element) {
        this.element = element;
    }

    attached() {
        $(".datepicker").datepicker();
        $(".datepicker").datepicker()
            .on("change", e => this.fireEvent(e.target, "input"));
    }

    createEvent(name) {
        var event = document.createEvent("Event");
        event.initEvent(name, true, true);
        return event;
    }

    fireEvent(element, name) {
        var event = this.createEvent(name);
        element.dispatchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

Here's the view-template:

```
<template>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox" checked.bind="value.checked & twoWay">${label}</label>
    </div>
    <div show.bind="datepicker == 'true' && value.checked">
        <label class="col-xs-1" style="padding: 0;">from</label>
        <div class="col-xs-11">
            <input class="form-control datepicker" type="text" value.bind="value.date & twoWay"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

I'm using it like this:

```
<checkbox datepicker="true" label.bind="'Checkbox label'" value.bind="filters['MyObject']" change.delegate="AlertSomething()"></checkbox>
```

The issue is when I select a date with the datepicker. The change event isn't getting fired. If I manually type something in, it gets fired. It also gets fired when the checkbox gets changed. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chances are that the problem is you are firing a custom event on the `input` element in your custom element's template and not on the custom element itself.

The line

```
.on("change", e => this.fireEvent(e.target, "input"));
```

needs to become

```
.on("change", e => this.fireEvent(this.element, "change"));
```

Also, slightly off-topic, please note that using `$(".datepicker")` is likely to cause bugs in your application if this custom element is used in more than one place. Instead of doing that, you should use the `ref` custom attribute to create a property on the viewmodel for the element you want to pass to jQuery. So, in this case, you'd need to do this in your template:

```
 <input class="form-control" ref="datepicker" type="text" 
        value.bind="value.date & twoWay"/>
```

And then change your VM code to use `$(this.datepicker)`

Comment: actually, I've come across an issue. How do I pass the ref value through to the custom element? I've got about 10 datepickers (custom elements) that I'm using in the same parent. How do I pass in a unique ref id?